# ImportError: No module named 'tesserwrap'

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

Tesseract is already installed in my system , tried installing tesserwrap but getting error as

**Installed Tesseract using command-**

```
  pip install tesseract
```

**Tried installing Tesserwrap module using command-**

```
pip install tesserwrap
 Collecting tesserwrap   Using cached tesserwrap-0.1.6.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        'ld' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        'ld' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_ftm6_ot\tesserwrap\setup.py", line 45, in <module>
            extra_lib_paths)
          File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_ftm6_ot\tesserwrap\setup.py", line 30, in find_closest_libname
            "Cannot find Tesseract via ldconfig, confirm it is installed.")
        Exception: Cannot find Tesseract via ldconfig, confirm it is installed.

        ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_ftm6_ot\tesserwrap\
```

**Is there any other way to install Tesserwrap?**

Comment: Please edit your question and include the steps you took to install tesserwrap.

Comment: @Soviut yes edited , check now

Answer (score 1):

tesserwrap is a wrapper for the program tesseract, not the python package. You need to install it. For me on Mac, the solution was:

```
brew install tesseract
```

Then install the python wrapper.